# C# VS2010 Setup Project makes no Icons and WinXP Error

Tags: c#, windows-xp, icons, installation

I created a Setup Project and it works in Windows 7, but no icons are shown in the shortcuts. I added the icons in the Form, in the Setup Project, in the Desktop Icon tab, in the Start menu tab and in the Add/Remove tab. I added the same icon for all the configurations...could it be a problem with the size of the icon?

Another question:
I am getting an error when I try to install it in Win XP computers...I have no messages to post in here, because my WinXP computer opens the VS2010 for debugging and the debugger has nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently. I've tried setting the shortcut icons to the app main output icon... didn't work. Then I've set added the same icon to the application folder and set to shortcut icons to that... didn't work either. The problem was the icon size. **I've generated a multi size icon** on https://icoconvert.com/ and behold. All the icons show properly now. Try doing that, maybe it wil fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Michal, but this was something I was working in 2012, I don't see those technologies as relevant anymore in 2019, maybe just for people dealing with legacy systems.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to put it there, since there might be someone still using the setup project in VS and looking for help.